# Are sqlite blobs (made of c/c++ arrays) platform independent?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, platform-independent

I know that in general sqlite is supposed to be platform independent ->
https://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html
. In my case I'd like to save 2dimensional c/c++ arrays into the db as blobs as there is no other way to do this. But since the value-types of the arrays as blobs are opaque to sqlite, the db has no chance to treat them platform independent and are therefore specific to one architecture, right?

Comment: Right. So beware of endianness, representation, padding, whatever. But why not simply serialize your data structure in a platform-independent way? (e. g. JSON, or if we are at it, another table, etc.)

Comment: So you mean serialize them as json and save them into the sqlite-db as text? I also thought about using [ejdb](https://github.com/Softmotions/ejdb). This way I could query the data.

Comment: Yes, but if you are serializing as JSON, you could as well just think up how to represent your data structure in the form of an SQL table.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about representing it differently in the schema. But the entity-type describes an event which consists of pairs with values at specific time points. I could of course do a separate table with (time, value) but the events would loose their order and I would have to query all of them for an event.

Comment: @0ax1 "but the events would loose their order" Not necessarily; you can sort by the primary key (which increases for every row you insert) or add a timestamp value to the event and sort based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user3477950 said, SQLite cannot know what BLOBs contain; to it, they're just an array of bytes. No conversion is done regarding endianness, representation, padding, etc.; the bytes it stores are exactly what you give it.